# bootstrap - how to fill a dropdown list

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

I am using bootstrap and trying to fill a dropdown list. It doesn't work. I only get the empty list. With the second HTML code (further below) everything works fine. What do I miss? I am using javascript.

Here is my javascript code:

```
var select = document.getElementById("ID1");
for (var j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
   var opt = arr[j];
   var el = document.createElement("option");
   el.textContent = opt;
   el.value = opt;
   select.appendChild(el);
}
```

My bootstrap HTML Code, which doesn´t work:

```
<div class="dropdown bootstrap-select show-tick"> 
<select class="selectpicker"  id='ID1'> 
</select>
</div>
```

With the following HTML code everything works fine:

```
<select class="custom-select custom-select-sm" id="ID1"></select>
```

Would be happy for some help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge, the class `selectpicker` does not exist in Bootstrap. In your second example you use the default [custom-select](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/input-group/#custom-select) of bootstrap.

However, according to your first html-snippet, it seems like you want to use the `selectpicker` class. There is a jQuery plugin called [bootstrap-select](https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/) to enhance the default bootstrap component. If you want to use this, you must add the corresponding stylesheets and js-files first.

**Edit:**
You mentioned, that the dropdown is shown but with no data in it. I am not quite familiar with this plugin, but managed to get a [working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/blazing-tree-pzyyx?file=/index.html) based on your code. Maybe it helps.

I don't know how your project is exactly structured, but in my example the key-part is this part:

```
$(function () {
  $(".selectpicker").selectpicker("refresh");
});
```

**Explanation:** The libraries are loaded and the bootstrap-select initialized, before the data is added to the select-element. Since bootstrap-select adds a button and some divs to create the dropdown, the original select-element is not visible and is probably only used as a data-source. By default the bootstrap-select is not reactive. Thus, we have to tell bootstrapselect to update its data.

Comment: Thank you, the droplist appears just fine and according to the log, the droplist is filled with data as I need it. The problem is, that the data isn´t shown on the page...

Comment: Ah ok. Sorry, I did not get that from your original problem description. I updated my answer with an example. I really hope that it solves your problem.

Comment: Sometimes it is so easy! It worked. Again what learned. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`textContent` is not a valid property of a `HTMLOptionElement` object (which is what is created when you use `document.createElement("option")`) - you want to set `el.text` instead, or better yet, create an `Option` element directly:

```js
var select = document.getElementById("ID1");
for (var j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
   var opt = arr[j];
   var el = new Option(opt, opt);
   select.appendChild(el);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Still have the problem, that the droplist does not get filled. I guess it it is a script problem. I do miss something... a bootstrap script...